# Python GUI for QGIS plugin ; how to add menu in QGIS 3.0

Tags: pyqgis

QGIS 3.0 is not backwardly compatible with QGIS 2.0, so currently my plugin (which was fine in the old version) is broken and I am trying to overhaul as required. The documentation seems to be taking a while to catch up with the software.

Would anyone be able to post some code which shows how to create a custom menu for a plugin in version 3.0?

My existing method (good in version 2.x / PyQt4) is this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

self.menu = QMenu( "&Whatever", self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar() )
actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
lastAction = actions[-1]
self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu( lastAction, self.menu )

mnuSub1 = self.menu.addMenu('Sub-menu')
mnuSub1.setIcon(QIcon(icoFolder + 'img1.png'))
mnuAction = mnuSub1.addAction("Do something...",self.RunSomething)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do exactly the same with PyQt5 [1] if you apply some minor changes.

- Import from `PyQt5`
- Many things have been split from the `QtGui` module to the `QtWidgets` module. Among them [`QMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html) (note the *qmake QT += widgets* entry).

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu

self.menu = QMenu("&Whatever", self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar())
actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
lastAction = actions[-1]
self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(lastAction, self.menu)
```

---

[1] Sidenote, the QGIS API itself is not actually relevant here, it's the [PyQt docs which count](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html). So I wouldn't blame the QGIS docs for not catching up.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.

(My point about documentation was, I think, based on a misconception. I was looking for help in the PyQGIS Developer Cookbook and thought that there was nothing for Version 3.0, but I see that there is. It is just not named as such. It is called 'Documentation QGIS Testing'.)

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3, QgisInterface provices

- **addPluginToDatabaseMenu**   Add action to the Database menu
- **addPluginToMenu**   Add action to the plugins menu
- **addPluginToRasterMenu** Add action to the Raster menu
- **addPluginToVectorMenu** Add action to the Vector menu
- **addPluginToWebMenu**    Add action to the Web menu

As documented in
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgisInterface.html